# Is there a way to see imported modules/files from the django shell?

Tags: python, django, import, python-import, interactive-shell

I have some lines of code that I use to practice `django_rest_framework` and I just pasted them in the python shell from `python manage.py shell`.

I have gotten some errors and would like to know what imports I already have.

Is there a function to figure out what was imported? This may be applicable to a python shell as well that isn't obtained from `django`.

This may not be necessary but here is the example code that I pasted in the shell while following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B38aDwUpcFc&ab_channel=ParwizForogh):

```
from .api_basic.models import Article
from .api_basic.serializers import ArticleSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

a = Article(
    title='Article Title',
    author = 'Parwiz',
    email = 'par@gmail.com'
)
b = Article(
    title='New Title',
    author = 'John',
    email = 'joh@gmail.com'
)

a.save()
b.save()

serializer = ArticleSerializer(a)
print(serializer.data) # gives a dict
content = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)


serializer2 = ArticleSerializer(Article.objects.all(), many=True)
content2 = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the imports using the built in `dir()` function. It actually lists out all the variables, classes, functions, imports etc. declared in the current python shell.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

[image]